Location of DataFrame cache
I am trying to understand how Spark cache() call caches data in the worker nodes.
For simplicity, let us assume:

The Dataframe has 2 partitions
Partition 0 is in worker node 0, and partition 1 is in worker node 1.

If a call to cache() is executed on the DataFrame:
A. Will partition 0 be cached in worker node 0's memory/heap and partition 1 in worker node 1?
OR
B. Will both workers have both partitions cached locally?

Nothing happens on cache() - caching only happens when you run an Action. Then, every executor will cache only the partitions it has processed.
